# Send my IP to remote server every time booting

Tags: linux, networking, boot, ip, dhcp

I want to send my computer's IP automatically every time it boots. I edit `/etc/rc.local`

```
sleep 10
ifconfig > /tmp/myip
scp /tmp/myip <server>
exit 0
```

I tried, and there is no `inet addr, Bcast, Mask` in `/tmp/myip`. I guess network starting after the script. So how to do it? Thank you very much!

Comment: What Operating System/distribution are you using?

Comment: depending on your OS, you might wish to use `ifconfig -a` or `ip all show`

Comment: Do you get anything in `/tmp/myip`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifconfig` does not show output,  probably because by the time it runs, the networking setup is not fully completed. Furthermore, there are not 100% guarantees the dynamic IP address won't change over the server uptime.

If using `dhclient`, move the script to the directory `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d`, so it executes *after* getting an IP address via DHCP. Debian usually populates this directory; if it does not exist it might have to be created.

The script can be changed for sending the IP address at boot, and every time it changes. Be aware that depending in your IP address DHCP lease lifetime, you *might* or *might not* be interested in copying it everytime.

If in an ISP/Internet environment, it might be also (more) interesting to use a dynamic DNS service.

Please do see this for more details [Better method for acting on IP address change from the ISP?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269567/better-method-for-acting-on-ip-address-change-from-the-isp)

and

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/dhclient-script.8.html

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on which dhcp client daemon are you using. Most distributions (on *bsd and linux) use `dhcpcd` or `dhclient`. In both cases, you could insert your script in the client configuration.

- `dhcpcd` runs `/etc/dhcpcd.sh` script, if it exists, each time a controlled interface goes up or down. You can simply insert your `scp` in this script.

  ```
  Hooking into DHCP events
    dhcpcd will run /etc/dhcpcd.sh, or the script specified by the -c,
    --script option. It will set $1 to a shell compatible file that holds
    various configuration settings obtained from the DHCP server and $2 to
    either up, down or new depending on the state of dhcpcd.  dhcpcd ignores
    the exist code of the script.
  ```
- `dhclient` invokes the `ETCDIR/dhclient-exit-hooks` script just after he set the interface. You can follow the instructions in `Hook` section of `dhclient-script` man page.

  ```
  After all processing has completed, CLIENTBINDIR/dhclient-script checks
  for  the  presence  of an executable ETCDIR/dhclient-exit-hooks script,
  which if present is invoked using the ´.´ command.  The exit status  of
  dhclient-script  will be passed to dhclient-exit-hooks in the exit_sta-
  tus shell variable, and will always be zero if the script succeeded  at
  the  task  for  which  it was invoked.   The rest of the environment as
  described previously for dhclient-enter-hooks is  also  present.    The
  ETCDIR/dhclient-exit-hooks  script  can modify the valid of exit_status
  to change the exit status of dhclient-script.
  ```

Comment: In the dhclient manual citation, you are lacking "All  executable scripts  in ETCDIR/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/* are also invoked."

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro probably I have an old version of dhclient manual (2.6.2) because it does not talk about `dhclient-exit-hooks.d`.

Comment: Jessie with dhclient 4.3.1 here. What are you running?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro sorry for the late reply. My current version of `ISC DHCP Client` is 4.2.6. I do not remember where I cut that `2.6.2` from :-(

Answer (score -2):

```
ifconfig ethx > /tmp/myip
```

x is your interface number like eth0

Comment: This captures the interface detail to a local file. But that doesn't answer the question.