# How can I give a Linux FTP server a domain name?

Tags: ftp, webserver, domain

I have a computer running Arch Linux headless with SSH server and proftpd server. It's for a personal use. But it's a bit annoying to run the IP address every-time to connect to it.

Can I give it a domain name for absolutely free?

Can I use that over the internet?

Comment: That's sad to hear, but how do the providers host them?

Comment: How many places do you connect to it from? Consider an /etc/hosts entry...

Comment: @Vlastimil Have a look at FreeDNS

Comment: Since I am surprised this question might actually have a solution, +1.

Answer (score 2):

For having a DNS name on the Internet, if you do not mind of having a choice between a couple of silly domain names like whateveryourname.mooo.com, you can use the services of dynamic DNS [FreeDNS](https://freedns.afraid.org) for free.

Basically you create a free account, and link it to a hostname of your choice suffixed to a couple of fixed domain names for the free tier accounts. Cant remember from the top of my head if the free tier allowed to define up to 6 different hostnames with one account/IP address.

Then they give you a daemon/URL to be accessed with a key, and each time you call it from your VM, the DNS name will be updated with your (dynamic) public address.

As in (demo example):

```
 curl https://sync.afraid.org/u/CyTXMbtq5cPnLjEg5vKHTPDE/
```

See my related question, for dealing with updating the name if the DHCP service gives you a different IP address with the VM/machine is online: [Better method for acting on IP address change from the ISP?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269567/better-method-for-acting-on-ip-address-change-from-the-isp)

Having then a DNS name that it is linked to the current IP address, it is far more easier to connect to a machine/service, especially when the IP address changes.

Bonus points: DD-WRT/OpenWRT, and I think PfSense, support FreeDNS on their firmware/OS.

FreeDNS is not the only one dynamic DNS name service with free tiers, you also have got No-IP https://www.noip.com

Comment: Hello! Thank you for a great point I did not know about at all. Btw, I do have OpenWRT in my router. +1

Comment: @Vlastimil same here ;)

Comment: Hi! I wanted to ask websites like FreeDNS are also created from somewhere. Since it's the internet, I believe I can get a domain name for free? I mean FreeDNS can't be relied on other DNS providers, they has to create their site from scratch. How can I create a site solely on my own without relying on anybody?

Is BIND helpful in such scenario?

Comment: I do not know of any free DNS provider allowing you your own BIND/DNS hosting on your side. Too much bureaucracy and hassle. You have to pay GoDaddy or some other DNS provider for that. I would advise not abusing comments for asking much more unrelated questions, you are welcome to open other questions, however I advise making an effort for them to be on topic.